# Insert new data to a table created from a view in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a view created from the query below:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "issue_view" AS 
SELECT *
FROM
  (
   SELECT
     affected_page,
     CAST("to_unixtime"(recent_detection) AS int) recent_detection,
     project_hash,
     issue_id,
     ...,
     "row_number"() OVER (PARTITION BY issue_id, recent_detection ORDER BY ts ASC) rn
   FROM
     "issue_pitr"
)  t
WHERE (t.rn = 1)
```

When I run another query to retrieve data from that view, it's very slow. I suppose since view doesn't have partitions?

If I create a new table from that view:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS issue_table
  WITH (format='parquet') AS
SELECT  * FROM  issue_view;
```

When querying from issue_table directly instead of issue_view, it's like 10 times faster. So I plan to drop the table once an hour and create a new one from the same view, but this will lead to a bit down time while the new table is created (I can make the code to query data from table, if error table not found then querying the view), but I wonder if we can have a better solution. Is there a way to insert only the recent change that we can detect from that view, so that I don't have to drop and re-create the whole table once an hour?

Comment: Do you have the `updated_at` column in the source view?

Comment: A View simply remembers the SQL -- it does not store any information. When you query from the view, it is running the SQL that you provided. Is the `issue_pitr` table stored in Parquet format? Or is it an External Table consisting of many smaller files?

Comment: @isc: Yes I do, just different naming but it represent the updated_at

Comment: @John: Yes it's in the Parquet format, what difference can it make in my use case here?

Comment: The performance of Amazon Athena is directly related to the way the source data is stored. The best format is Snappy-compressed Parquet formats. You were saying that querying your data was slow, which could happen if it was coming from a large number of small files, especially CSV format. The fact that your `issue_table` is so much faster suggests that it is being stored in a _much_ better way than the original data. That's unexpected, since you are saying that `issue_pitr` is already in Parquet format.

Comment: issue_pitr is stored under Snappy-compressed Parquet format, and issue_table is created from the view with the query in my original post :)

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose since view doesn't have partitions?

Interesting hypothesis but I highly doubt so

> When querying from issue_table directly instead of issue_view, it's like 10 times faster

This is quite expected. From the [Athena views docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html):

> A view in Amazon Athena is a logical table, not a physical table. The query that defines a view runs each time the view is referenced in a query.

While creating the new table will lead in the query execution and storing the result ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html)) and all the following queries will work with the processed result set (hence the speed up and need to refresh it from time to time) because 1) there is no need to perform the query logic again 2) the resulting set can be significantly smaller.

One thing you can try looking into is reusing the query results. Since the end  of 2022 Athena allows caching the results (requires Athena engine version 3) on per query basis (have not used it, I assume it can be combined with using views). Check the following articles/docs:

- [Amazon Athena announces Query Result Reuse to accelerate queries](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-athena-query-result-reuse-accelerate-queries/)
- [Reusing query results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/reusing-query-results.html)

Comment: I think because view is just a logical, not physical table, so it can only benefit from the partitions of the table that it's created from, and view can't have its own partitions. I think this is why "If you are creating views through the AWS GlueData Catalog, you must include the PartitionKeys parameter and set its value to an empty list".

How can caching query help with my use case here? I want the data to be freshly updated, while caching will just use the old data :(

Comment: @iron_bat it is an alternative approach to creating table where you will not need to drop and recreate it, it will be done for you (though in a slightly different way)